# add CssClass to <asp:Label> conditionally

Tags: css, .net, class, label, conditional-statements

I have the following code.
Only if it evaluates to true, I'd like to add a css class

```
lblMonth.Text = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Month"]) > 0 ? "*" : string.Empty;
```

and in the front

```
<td><asp:Label ID="lblMonth" runat="server"></asp:Label></td>
```

I've tried the following to no avail

```
if (Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Month"]) > 0) { lblMonth.Text = "*"; lblMonth.Attributes.Add("class", "MyFunClassName"); }
```

I've tested the first string and it returns the asterisk. So I know its evaluating to true.
And in my attempt to add the class, the asterisk is still being generated. So I know the conditions are correct.

**Any guess what is wrong with my Attribute.Add statement?**
ie. why isn't the css then added?

I've tried this also and its not adding the style

```
if (Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Month"]) > 0) { lblMonth.Text = "*"; lblMonth.CssClass = "MyFunClassName"; }
```

Am I misunderstanding how  works? Can it not receive a style and wrap a div/span around it ... Do I need to somehow generate that conditionally?

Comment: Set lblMonth.CssClass, and forget about the attributes.

Comment: hmm thats not working either.

Comment: Yes - you are misunderstanding this. CssClass specifies the name of CSS class you want assigned to the Label.  You should define these in your styleshets.  You can have two different classes defined, and then based on your if statement, assign one of them to the CssClass property. IE - lblMonth.CssClass = "MyTrueClass" or lblMonth.CssClass = "MyFalseClass"

Comment: Sorry when I say style, I mean applying the CSS Class Name. I'm looking in the sourcecode (and Firebug) and no classname appears. I've changed my style/cssclass name to better demonstrate. Isn't this how you would add the style/cssclass name....   `lblMonth.CssClass = "MyFunClassName"; `

Comment: Where are you placing the C# IF block of code? Is it in Page Load method? I mean, your code has to get triggered somehow?

Comment: the if statement is in the .aspx.cs file
and the <asp:Label> is in the .aspx
I think something else is going on. I can't even get a css name to show up 
`<asp:Label ID="lblMonth" runat="server" CssClass="doesThisWork"></asp:Label>` I get the "*" but no wrapping --> <span class="doesThisWork">. Just the asterisk text.  ... that SHOULD work , right?

Comment: Is the month coming across in your datatable row correct? Is it coming over as 1-12, or as January-December?

Comment: its coming across as 1-12

Comment: Not sure.  Why don't you make a JS Fiddle, so we can see?